# Exception while parsing the url

Tags: android, url-parsing

I am getting the exception while parsing the content from am url. The exception i am getting is given below.

```
10-16 12:46:59.373: E/AndroidRuntime(4362): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12
10-16 12:46:59.373: E/AndroidRuntime(4362): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-16 12:46:59.373: E/AndroidRuntime(4362):     at com.android.gyan.SearchResults$4.run(SearchResults.java:162)
10-16 12:46:59.373: E/AndroidRuntime(4362):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362): Activity com.android.gyan.SearchResults has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4056d3b0 that was originally added here
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.android.gyan.SearchResults has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4056d3b0 that was originally added here
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:95)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at com.android.gyan.SearchResults.ParsingCall(SearchResults.java:147)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at com.android.gyan.SearchResults.onCreate(SearchResults.java:137)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The which i am using to parse is this.

```
public void ParsingCall(final String urlFirst) {
    final Bundle b = new Bundle();
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SearchResults.this, " ",
            "Searching.....", true, false);
    progressDialog.setIcon(-1);

    progressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            LyricsData dataContent = null;

            dataContent = LyricsParse.Parse(urlFirst);
            Message msg = new Message();
            {

                {
                    if(dataContent.contentList != null) {
                        b.putStringArrayList("contentList",
                            dataContent.contentList);
                    }else {
                        //dataContent.contentList[0] = {"No value"};
                        b.putString("contentList",
                                "No value");
                    }
                    if(dataContent.optionNameArrayList != null)
                    b.putStringArrayList("optionNameArrayList",
                            dataContent.optionNameArrayList);
                    else
                        b.putString("optionNameArrayList",
                                "No value");
                }
            }

            msg.setData(b);

            handler.sendMessage(msg);

        }
    }).start();
}
```

I have also written an handler which will get the message and from that getting data and setting those to the view i am having in the activity. Please note that this exception is not getting every time. It is getting very rarely.

Comment: what is the line SearchResults.java:162??

Comment: what's on line 162 ? (my guess is it is handler.sendMessage, as it is the only element without visible initialization)

Answer (score 2):

There is error in your run method.Place debug point at starting of run method and you will a variable which is being initialized to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

remove one line..

```
progressDialog.setIcon(-1);

progressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
```

Comment: if you read the question you'll see that the error is in the run method

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` at line 147 of your `SearchResults.java` file as per this line:

```
10-16 12:46:59.783: E/WindowManager(4362):  at com.android.gyan.SearchResults.ParsingCall(SearchResults.java:147)
```

Please make sure that all the variables on this line are initialized and are not set to null. I'm guessing you are calling `ProgressDialog.show()` but you haven't initialized your `ProgressDialog` variable or your initialization is out of scope.